# RelaychainwithChainbridge

Tags: substrate-node-template, relay-chain, substrate-contracts-node, substrate-node, chainbridge

We have tried to connect my relay chain with Chainbridge, but I got errors (SUB to ETH and ETH to SUB). I could not replace the existing relay chain with my relay chain. Please let me know the solution or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.